# Implementing a quicksort algorithm for a vector of objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, quicksort, implementation

I was given an assignment to implement a quicksort algorithm into my C++ program. The homework is a part of series which started with objects and inheritance, but our lector didn't really explain quicksort to us.

However, I can't really understand how do I select the vector of an object that is to be sorted and how do I set the low and high limits.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T AskFor(string text) {
  cout << text << endl;
  T result;
  cin >> result;
  cin.clear();
  return result;
}

class Vehicle {
public:
  Vehicle(string producer, string model, int year)
    : model(model) {
      setProducer(producer);
      setYear(year);
  }

  void output() {
    cout << "  producer(vehicle): " << producer << endl;
    cout << "  model(vehicle): " << model << endl;
    cout << "  year(vehicle): " << year << endl;
  }

  void setProducer(const string producer) {
    if (isProducerValid(producer)) {
      this->producer = producer;
    }
  }

  string getProducer() const {
    return producer;
  }

  void setModel(const string model) {
    this->model = model;
  }

  string getModel() const {
    return model;
  }

  void setYear(const int year) {
    if (isYearValid(year)) {
      this->year = year;
    }
  }

  int getYear() const {
    return year;
  }

  static bool isYearValid(int year) {
    return year >= 1950 && year <= 2016;
  }

  static bool isProducerValid(string producer) {
    static string PRODUCERS[] { "Toyota", "Audi", "BMW", "Mercedes" };
    return find(begin(PRODUCERS), end(PRODUCERS), producer) != end(PRODUCERS);
  }

private:
  string producer;
  string model;
  int year;
};

class Vendor {
public:
    Vendor(string v_name, string address, string phone, vector<string> delivery)
        : v_name(v_name),
        address(address),
        delivery(delivery) {
        setPhone(phone);
    }

    void setVendorName(const string v_name) {
        this->v_name = v_name;
    }

    string getVendorName() const {
        return v_name;
    }

    void setAddress(const string address) {
        this->address = address;
    }

    string getAddress() const {
        return address;
    }

    void setPhone(const string phone) {
        this->phone = phone;
    }

    string getPhone() const {
        return phone;
    }

    void setDelivery(const vector<string> delivery) {
        this->delivery = delivery;
    }

    vector<string> getDelivery() const {
        return delivery;
    }

    static bool isPhoneNumber(string phone) {
        if (phone.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return all_of(begin(phone), end(phone), isdigit);
    }

private:
    string v_name;
    string address;
    string phone;
    vector<string> delivery;
};

class SparePart {
public:
  SparePart(string id, string name, Vehicle* v, int price, int time_to_replace,
            bool is_new = true, string description = "", string manual = "")
    : id(id),
      name(name),
      vehicle(v),
      price(price),
      time_to_replace(time_to_replace),
      is_new(is_new),
      description(description),
      manual(manual) {}

  double replacementPrice() {
    return price + time_to_replace * 20;
  }

  int warranty() const {
    return is_new ? 36 : 3;
  }

  virtual void output() {
    cout << "  ID: " << id << endl;
    cout << "  name: " << name << endl;
    vehicle->output();
    if (is_new) cout << "  new" << endl; 
    else {
      cout << "  recycled" << endl;
    }
    cout << "  description: " << description << endl;
    cout << "  manual: " << manual << endl;
  }

  virtual ~SparePart() = 0;

  void setId(const string id) {
    this->id = id;
  }

  string getId() const {
    return id;
  }

  void setName(const string name) {
    this->name = name;
  }

  string getName() const {
    return name;
  }

  void setDescription(const string description) {
    this->description = description;
  }

  string getDescription() const {
    return description;
  }

  void setManual(const string manual) {
    this->manual = manual;
  }

  string getManual() const {
    return manual;
  }

  void setPrice(const double price) {
    this->price = price;
  }

  double getPrice() const {
    return price;
  }

  void setIsNew(const bool is_new) {
     this->is_new = is_new;
  }

  void setTimeToReplace(const int time_to_replace) {
    this->time_to_replace = time_to_replace;
  }

  int getTimeToReplace() const {
    return time_to_replace;
  }

private:
  string id;
  string name;
  string description;
  string manual;
  double price;
  bool is_new;
  int time_to_replace;
  Vehicle* vehicle;
};

class AvailableSparePart : public SparePart {
public:
  AvailableSparePart(string id, string name, Vehicle* v, int price, int time_to_replace,
    int quantity, string location, bool is_new = true, string description = "", string manual = "")
    : SparePart(id, name, v, price, time_to_replace, is_new, description, manual),
      quantity(quantity),
      location(location) {}

  double price() {
    return replacementPrice();
  }

  int time() {
    return getTimeToReplace();
  }

  void output() {
    cout << "Available Spare Part" << endl;
    SparePart::output();
    cout << "  time: " << time() << endl;
    cout << "  price: " << price() << endl;
  }

  void setQuantity(const int quantity) {
    this->quantity = quantity;
  }

  int getQuantity() const {
    return quantity;
  }

  void setLocation(const string location) {
    this->location = location;
  }

  string getLocation() const {
    return location;
  }

private:
  int quantity;
  string location;
};

class ContractedSparePart : public SparePart {
public:
  ContractedSparePart(string id, string name, Vehicle* v, int price, int time_to_replace,
    int delivery_time, double delivery_price, Vendor* vendor, bool is_new = true,
    string description = "", string manual = "")
    : SparePart(id, name, v, price, time_to_replace, is_new, description, manual),
      delivery_time(delivery_time),
      delivery_price(delivery_price),
      vendor(vendor) {}

  double price() {
    return replacementPrice();
  }

  int time() {
    return getTimeToReplace() + delivery_time;
  }

  void output() {
    cout << "Contracted Spare Part" << endl;
    SparePart::output();
    cout << "  time: " << time() << endl;
    cout << "  price: " << price() << endl;
  }

  void setDeliveryTime(const int delivery_time) {
    this->delivery_time = delivery_time;
  }

  int getDeliveryTime() const {
    return delivery_time;
  }

  void setDeliveryPrive(const double delivery_price) {
    this->delivery_price = delivery_price;
  }

  double getDeliveryPrice() const {
    return delivery_price;
  }

private:
  Vendor* vendor;
  int delivery_time;
  double delivery_price;
};

enum class Action {
  ADD_VEHICLE,
  ADD_VENDOR,
  ADD_PART,
  ADD_PART_QUANTITY,
  LIST_PARTS,
  CALCULATE_COST,
  EXIT
};

Action menu() {
  string prompt = "Choose an option:\n"
                  "1. Add a new vehicle\n"
                  "2. Add a new vendor\n"
                  "3. Add a new spare part\n"
                  "4. Add part quantity\n"
                  "5. List spare parts\n"
                  "6. Calculate the cost of replacement\n"
                  "7. Exit";
  while (true) {
    switch (AskFor<int>(prompt)) {
    case 1:
      return Action::ADD_VEHICLE; break;
    case 2:
      return Action::ADD_VENDOR; break;
    case 3:
      return Action::ADD_PART; break;
    case 4: 
      return Action::ADD_PART_QUANTITY; break;
    case 5:
      return Action::LIST_PARTS; break;
    case 6:
      return Action::CALCULATE_COST; break;
    case 7:
      return Action::EXIT; break;
    default:
      cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 6" << endl;
    }
  }
}

struct PartAndNumber {
  PartAndNumber(SparePart* part, int number)
    : part(part), number(number) {}

  SparePart* part;
  int number;
};

void add_vehicle(vector<Vehicle*>& vehicles);
void add_vendor(vector < Vendor*>& vendors);
void add_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, const vector<Vehicle*>& vehicles, const vector<Vendor*>& vendors);
void add_available_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, Vehicle* vehicle);
void add_contracted_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, Vehicle* vehicle, const vector<Vendor*>& vendors);
void add_part_number(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts);
void list_parts(const vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts);
void calculate_cost(const vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts);

int main() {
  vector<Vehicle*> vehicles;
  vector<PartAndNumber*> parts;
  vector<Vendor*> vendors;

  while (true) {
    Action action = menu();
    switch (action) {
    case Action::ADD_VEHICLE:
      add_vehicle(vehicles);
      break;
    case Action::ADD_VENDOR:
      add_vendor(vendors);
      break;
    case Action::ADD_PART:
      add_part(parts,vehicles,vendors);
      break;
    case Action::ADD_PART_QUANTITY:
      add_part_number(parts);
      break;
    case Action::LIST_PARTS:
      list_parts(parts);
      break;
    case Action::CALCULATE_COST:
      calculate_cost(parts);
      break;
    case Action::EXIT:
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

void add_vehicle(vector<Vehicle*>& vehicles) {
  string producer;
  while (true) {
    producer = AskFor<string>("New vehicle (producer): ");
    if (Vehicle::isProducerValid(producer)) {
      break;
    }
    cout << "Producer name is invalid. Try again." << endl;
  }

  string model = AskFor<string>("New vehicle (model):");

  int year;
  while (true) {
    year = AskFor<int>("New vehicle (year):");
    if (Vehicle::isYearValid(year)) {
      break;
    }
    cout << "Year is invalid. Try again." << endl;
  }

  vehicles.push_back(new Vehicle(producer, model, year));

  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
  cout << "The vehicle was added to the database" << endl;
  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
}

void add_vendor(vector <Vendor*>& vendors) {
  string v_name = AskFor<string>("New vendor (name): ");
  string address = AskFor<string>("New vendor (address): ");
  string phone;

  while (true) {
    phone = AskFor<string>("New vendor (phone):");
    if (Vendor::isPhoneNumber(phone)) {
      break;
    }
    else cout << "Phone is invalid. Try again." << endl;
  }

  vector<string> delivery;
  string del;
  do {
    cout << "New vendor(delivery) or q to stop: ";
    if (del != "") {
      delivery.push_back(del);
    }
  } while ((cin >> del) && del != "q");

  vendors.push_back(new Vendor(v_name, address, phone, delivery));

  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
  cout << "The vendor was added to the database" << endl;
  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
}

void add_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, const vector<Vehicle*>& vehicles, const vector<Vendor*>& vendors) {
  string prompt = "Choose the type of spare part : Available(1) or Contracted(2); or q to exit : ";
  do {
    string model = AskFor<string>("Vehicle model: ");

    Vehicle* vehicle = nullptr;
    for (auto v : vehicles) {
      if (v->getModel() == model) {
        vehicle = v;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (vehicle == nullptr) {
      cout << "Could not find a vehicle with this model." << endl;
      return;
    }

    switch (AskFor<char>(prompt)) {
      case '1':
      add_available_part(parts, vehicle);
      return;
      break;
    case '2':
      add_contracted_part(parts, vehicle, vendors);
      return;
      break;
    case 'q':
      return;
      break;
    default:
      cout << "No such option!";
    }
  } while (true);
}

void add_available_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, Vehicle* vehicle) {
  string id = AskFor<string>("New spare part(id): ");

  for (auto p : parts) {
    if (p->part->getId() == id) {
      cout << "Already available" << endl;
      return;
    }
  }

  string name = AskFor<string>("New spare part(name): ");
  int price = AskFor<int>("New spare part(price): ");
  int time_to_replace = AskFor<int>("New spare part(time to replace): ");
  bool is_new = AskFor<bool>("New spare part(1 for new, 0 for recycled): ");
  string description = AskFor<string>("New spare part(description): ");
  string manual = AskFor<string>("New spare part(manual): ");
  int quantity = AskFor<int>("New spare part(quantity): ");
  string location = AskFor<string>("New spare part(location): ");

  auto part = new AvailableSparePart(id, name, vehicle, price, time_to_replace, quantity, location, is_new, description, manual);
  parts.push_back(new PartAndNumber(part, 0));

  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
  cout << "The spare part was added to the database" << endl;
  cout << "**************************************" << endl;

}

void add_contracted_part(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts, Vehicle* vehicle, const vector<Vendor*>& vendors) {
  string id = AskFor<string>("New spare part(id): ");

  for (auto p : parts) {
    if (p->part->getId() == id) {
      cout << "Already available" << endl;
      return;
    }
  }

  string v_name = AskFor<string>("New spare part(vendor name): ");

  Vendor* vendor = nullptr;
  for (auto v : vendors) {
    if (v->getVendorName() == v_name) {
      vendor = v;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (vendor == nullptr) {
    cout << "Could not find a vendor with this name." << endl;
    return;
  }

  string name = AskFor<string>("New spare part(name): ");
  int price = AskFor<int>("New spare part(price): ");
  int time_to_replace = AskFor<int>("New spare part(time to replace): ");
  bool is_new = AskFor<bool>("New spare part(1 for new, 0 for recycled): ");
  string description = AskFor<string>("New spare part(description): ");
  string manual = AskFor<string>("New spare part(manual): ");
  int delivery_time = AskFor<int>("New spare part(delivery time): ");
  double delivery_price = AskFor<double>("New spare part(delivery price): ");

  auto part = new ContractedSparePart(id, name, vehicle, price, time_to_replace, delivery_time, delivery_price, vendor, is_new, description, manual);
  parts.push_back(new PartAndNumber(part, 0));

  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
  cout << "The spare part was added to the database" << endl;
  cout << "**************************************" << endl;
}

void add_part_number(vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts) {
  string id = AskFor<string>("Spare part (id): ");
  for (auto p : parts) {
    if (p->part->getId() == id) {
      int parts_number = AskFor<int>("Number of parts: ");
      p->number = parts_number;
      cout << "***************************************************" << endl;
      cout << "The number of spare parts was added to the database" << endl;
      cout << "***************************************************" << endl;
      return;
    }
  }
  cout << "A spare part with this ID is not available."; 
}

void list_parts(const vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts) {
    double total_price = 0;
  for (auto p : parts) {
    p->part->output();
    cout << endl;
    double total_current_price = p->part->replacementPrice() * p->part->getTimeToReplace();
    total_price = +total_current_price;
  }
  quicksort(parts, , parts.back);
  cout << "The total price is" << total_price << endl;
}

void calculate_cost(const vector<PartAndNumber*>& parts) {
  string id = AskFor<string>("Spare part(id): ");
  for (auto p : parts) {
    if (p->part->getId() == id) {
      cout << "The cost for replacement is $" << p->part->replacementPrice() << endl;
      return;
    }
  }
  cout << "A spare part with this ID is not available.";
}

SparePart::~SparePart() {}

template <class Comparable>
void quicksort(vector<Comparable>& a)
{
    quicksort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
}

template <class Comparable>
void quicksort(vector<Comparable>& a, double low, double high)
{
    if (low + 10 > high) {
        insertionSort(a);
    }
    else {
        double middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[middle] < a[low]) swap(a[low], a[middle]);
        if (a[high] < a[low]) swap(a[low], a[high]);
        if (a[high] < a[middle]) swap(a[middle], a[high]);
        Comparable pivot = a[middle];
        swap(a[middle], a[high - 1]);


        int i, j;
        for (i = low, j = high - 1; ;) {
            while (a[++i] < pivot) {}
            while (pivot < a[--j]) {}

            if (i < j) swap(a[i], a[j]);
            else break;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[high - 1]);

        quicksort(a, low, i - 1);
        quicksort(a, i + 1, high); 
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure I get your problem. To sort a certain `vector`, call the function `quicksort` with that `vector`.

Comment: quicksort is pretty straightforward: find a random index in your vector, split the data into three groups, those smaller than the item at the pivot, those equal to it, and those larger, then recursively call quick sort on the smaller and largest lists. something like qs(smaller) || equal || qs(left) where || is a vector concatenation.

Comment: A vector can be accessed in the same way as an array. And there are *untold many* implementations of quicksort on an array

Comment: I can see a problem for beginners: a sub-array of an array is itself an array, but an iterator range into a vector isn't a vector. Here's the relevant tip: `std::vector<T>` is a convenient wrapper, but it is intentionally a thin wrapper around a `T[size]` array. `&vec[0]` is the address where that array starts. Now quicksort that array.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of Your vector are pointers! The easiest way is to add to class PartAndNumber

```
operator<(const PartAndNumber *other)
{
    return this->part->id - other->part->id;
}
```